# javascript regex paragraph not ending with full stop

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a document containing lots of paragraphs. Some of these are subheadings, which are identifiable because they do not end with a full stop, like this:

```
<p>This is a title</p>
<p>This is a sentence.</p>
<p>This is a sentence.</p>
<p>This is a sentence.</p>
<p>This is a sentence.</p>
<p>This is a title</p>
<p>This is a sentence.</p>
<p>This is a sentence.</p>
<p>This is a sentence.</p>
<p>This is a sentence.</p>
<p>This is a title</p>
<p>This is a sentence.</p>
<p>This is a sentence.</p>
<p>This is a sentence.</p>
<p>This is a sentence.</p>
```

I want to make the titles go into an h3 tag but not the sentences. So I need to find and replace all paragraphs not ending in a full stop. I need to do this with javascript I have tried the following but each fails. In each case the text is first read into a variable called body.

```
body = body.replace(/<p>(.*?)(?!\.)<\/p>/gi, "<h3>$1</h3>");
```

That just makes everything bold

This would work, I think:

```
body = body.replace(/<p>(.*?)(?<!\.)<\/p>/gi, "<h3>$1</h3>");
```

but javascript does not recognise negative look behind.

Any ideas how I do this?

Comment: Instead of trying to use regexp on HTML, which is always a slippery slope, I would pull out all the `p` elements, check their content, and add a class to the ones that don't end in a full stop.

Comment: Do you mean this? `<p>([^\.]*?)<\/p>`

Comment: Thanks Washington, I think you're right except I don't think you need to escape in a character class. So: `<p>([^.]*?)<\/p>`

Comment: Note also, Washington, that this doesn't capture this title `<p>1.2 million people like regex</p>` but as I mention below, this doesn't really matter to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do the replacement paragraph per paragraph, which would be cleaner that doing a regex on the whole HTML:

```js
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName('p'), function(p){
     if (!/[.?!]\s*$/.test(p.innerHTML)) p.outerHTML="<h3>"+p.innerHTML+"</h3>";
});
```

```html
<p>This is a title</p>
<p>This is a sentence.</p>
<p>This is a sentence.</p>
<p>You want to handle questions, right?</p>
<p>I'm sure you do!</p>
<p>This is a title containing 1.2 million</p>
<p>This is a sentence.</p>
<p>This is a sentence.</p>
<p>This is a sentence.</p>
<p>This is a sentence.</p>
<p>This is a title</p>
<p>This is a sentence.</p>
<p>This is a sentence.</p>
<p>This is a sentence.</p>
<p>This is a sentence.</p>
```

This way there's no problem if your HTML evolves (will you really always  have only P elements?).

Comment: Why do you need the `\s*` part of the expression ?

Comment: @sln It's very frequent to have unwanted spaces in HTML (often they're new lines at the start or end).

Comment: Ok, but I just don't see whitespace have anything to do with `[.?!]` like who care's if there is optional space.

Comment: Thanks Denys. I think this will be the way to go. I need to adapt it to work on my variable as I'm not working on an html document, but that should be easy enough. I will mark this as answered once I've confirmed I can do that. Note: your code won't capture this title: `<p>1.2 million people don't care</p>` even though it doesn't end with a full stop. But such an exception will be rare, so I can live with it.

Comment: For those that are interested, this is an adaption of Denys' code that will work on the text string variable I explain I am using in the question. Note: this does not work on the exception I define in the comment above. I'd be interested if anyone can think of a way to capture this exception too, but I don't require it. body = body.replace(/<p>([^.?!]*?)<\/p>/gi, "<h3>$1</h3>");

Comment: @DrBloke I realize after reading your comment that I forgot a $. You're probably more interested in this fixed regex.

Answer (score 1):

You're over thinking it. Keep it simple!

```
body = body.replace(/<p>(.*?[^.])<\/p>/gi, "<h3>$1</h3>");
//                          ^^^^
```

No need for the lookarounds, just match a non-period character at the end of a 0+ dot-match-all.

<sub>***Note:*** *I would use Denys' solution (which I +1'd) since [regex isn't a good idea for HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).*</sub>

---

***Update:***

Check out [this expression](https://regex101.com/r/sF6kS4/1):

```
<p>((?:.(?!\.))*?)<\/p>
```

This lazily loops through a non-capturing group containing a negative lookahead 0+ times. The only exception here is it doesn't check the first character for a period (since there is one initial dot-match-all), but this can be [fixed with a lookahead at the beginning](https://regex101.com/r/sF6kS4/2):

```
<p>((?=[^.])(?:.(?!\.))*?)<\/p>
```

Comment: Care to comment -1? I realize regular expressions aren't the best way to solve this, but I still think OP should know how to fix their expression.

Comment: I agree that this doesn't seem to warrant a -1 (a small warning about HTML and regexes would make it better, though)

Comment: Thanks Sam. However, I think this would replace `<p>Sentence.</p><p>Title</p><p>Sentence.</p>` with this `<h3>Sentence.</p><p>Title</h3><p>Sentence.</p>` This may be my fault as I have presented the text in multi-line format for clarity, and in that case your code seems to works. In reality all the text is on one line.